# Laravel relationships - hasMany, hasOne

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, an order model and an address model. Each line in the orders table has an address ID which correlates to a line in the address table.

in the order model...

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrderAddress::class);
}
```

in the address model...

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

However, I want to access the address from the order model

```
$order->address
```

This shows an error becuase I do not have any order_id fields in the address table. Eventually I want it to be possible to check if the address already exits in the table (i.e. for repeat orders from the same customer) and then I can reuse this same row across multiple orders.

So in summary, an order can only ever have 1 address but an address can have many orders. I have setup my models like this (I think) but the following error is thrown:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_addresses.order_id' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You might consider having each line item being its own Model within an Order model, so they can `belongsTo` an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a rather common confusion, but the inverse of `hasMany` is [`belongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships).

What you need is:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OrderAddress::class);
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you. I have read the comments in the other answer and this one does feel like it makes sense (with my limited knowledge). Changing to belongsTo fixes my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that error is because you either don't have a foreign key setup in the table, 
If you are using a different foreign key from the default naming convention then you have to specify the foreign key's name. You can even specify the primary key if you don't use the expected 'id'.

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }

public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\OrderAddress', 'foreign_key');
}
```

Laravel assumes you use database naming best practices where:

- Tables = table_name
- pivot tables = tablea_tableb
- primary keys = id
- foreign key = referencedtable_id

If you don't follow that standard, Eloquent is flexible enough to offer you a parameter to change it.

Read more about eloquent relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: The problem is, that doing `hasOne()` like that will work for basic cases, but it's wrong and will cause problems if you want to use some relationship methods on it. If an order `hasMany` addresses, then address `belongsTo` an order. Like I said in my answer, it's a common confusion. I have no idea how this is getting upvotes, please read the documentation you linked.

Comment: @devk completely agree. And I personally don’t use one-one relationships when I reference an address table for that reason. The reason he’s getting his error however is because Eloquent can’t find the foreign key with the name it expects.  A hasOne can work in this instance if implemented properly.

Comment: Yes, because it's looking for the foreign key on the `order_addresses` table, which is how a `hasOne` relationship works. If they just switched it to `belongsTo`, it would look for the foreign key on the `orders` table instead, and if they set up their database correctly and following conventions, it will work without any other additions.

Comment: In this case I am only using the id columns as the joining columns, so I believe the foreign keys are not the issue. i.e. in address table - the id column is the primary key. In the orders table, this primary key is referenced in the address_id column

Comment: The foreign key attribute is still a new thing for me though, so thanks for pointing this out! (I am only a few weeks into my Laravel journey!)

Comment: That's what I was pointing out in my first comment. The `hasOne` would work for the basic examples in OP's case, if he did that: `$this->hasOne(OrderAddress::class, 'id', 'order_address_id')`. But that's misusing the relationship and will fail if you try to chain some specific methods off of it. The `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships are exactly the same from SQL point of view. The difference is that using `hasOne` Laravel will not create an array of the related models, but only attach an object to it. It's purely a convenience for not having to use `$parent->child[0]`.